# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden Exception

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I found this error while dumping the stats from analytics as source.

Can anyone say what could be this..??

```
public Get getAnalyticsReportDefination() {
    String month = ((fromCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (fromCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) : "" + (fromCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
    String date = (fromCal.get(Calendar.DATE) < 10 ? "0" + fromCal.get(Calendar.DATE) : "" + fromCal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    String toMonth = ((toCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (toCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) : "" + (toCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
    String toDate = (toCal.get(Calendar.DATE) < 10 ? "0" + toCal.get(Calendar.DATE) : "" + toCal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    String TimeStamp1 = fromCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + month + "-" + date;
    String TimeStamp2 = toCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + toMonth + "-" + toDate;
    log.info("Google Analytics Stats for date range " +TimeStamp1 + " to " +TimeStamp2);
    String accessToken = gleTokenInf.getAccessToken();
    String refreshToken = gleTokenInf.getRefreshToken();
    Analytics analytics = null;
    NetHttpTransport netHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();

    if (accessToken != null && refreshToken != null) {
        JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
         GoogleCredential credential =new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(netHttpTransport)
                                               .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build();
                           credential.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                           credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        analytics=new Analytics.Builder(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        try {
            //AT a time we can get only 7 dimensions and 10 metrics
            apiQuery = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + gleTokenInf.getProfileId(), TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2,getMetrics());
            apiQuery.setDimensions(getDimensions());
            StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();
            int len = FilterConditions.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   source.append(FilterConditions[i]).append(filterExpression).append(FilterValues[i]).append(FilterType); 
                }
            apiQuery.setFilters(source.substring(0, source.length() - 1));
            gaData = apiQuery.execute();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return apiQuery;
}
```

The error is:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics/quotas?project=433676821622",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics/quotas?project=433676821622"
  } ],
  "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console
}

----------

metrics: ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:itemRevenue,ga:transactionShipping,ga:transactionTax

dimensions: ga:campaign,ga:adGroup
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of _"Daily Limit Exceeded"_ is unclear?

Comment: Editing doesn't help. The error is telling you that you have exceeded the number of queries per day that you are allowed to perform.

Comment: Then what could be the solution.

Comment: Wait until tomorrow, like the error message says.  What does the following phrase mean to you _"Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console"_?

Answer (score 0):

There are several quotas you should be aware of when using Google analytics API.

The first is your application can make max 50000 request per day.  The second is each view you are trying to access can make a max of 10000 requests per day.

> Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT)

Means that you have exceeded one of those quotas.  The easiest way to figure out which one it is would be to try and make a request using a different view.  if it works then you know you blew out the quota on the first view.   If it doesn't it means that you blew out the quota on your project.   Which ever quota it is you blew out you will not be able to access the API again from that until the Quota resets at mid night west cost USA time.

You can request an extension of the 50000 requests per project. Via Google developer console where you enabled the analytics api and under the quota section.  It takes around a month to get an extension so its best to apply when you are using 80% of your quota each day.

You can not request an extension of the 10000 requests per day.